# Double fork from shell to run java process / jar

Tags: java, bash, fork, processbuilder

I have a Java application that needs to spawn another Java application. This second java application is long lived and might outlive the original java application. It's basically a big while loop that executes some networking code, and is not intended to terminate unless a specific condition happens. To launch this application, I use a bash script to double fork it, so that the original java application doesn't wait for it to complete:

How the original java app launches the shell script:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "myshellscript",
    "-a", "somearg",
    "-b", "anotherarg");

final Process process = processBuilder.start();
process.waitFor();
if (process.exitValue() != 0)
{
  // do something
}
```

The contents of the shell script:

```
fork() {
   echo "Going to fork" >> /tmp/output.log
   (setsid java -jar ./anotherapplication.jar "$@" &);
   echo "Exited" >> /tmp/output.log
}
fork "$@"
```

In "output.log", I see "Going to fork" and "Exited" messages, but I never see any logs from the "anotherapplication.jar" app, which makes me think it doesn't start successfully. It also doesn't show in the output of `ps aux` either, so it definitely isn't running. Is this the right way to start the second application, or am I not starting it correctly?

Comment: If you run `sleep 3600` instead, does it show up? If so, the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Does anotherapplication.jar read any input from standard input?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson no, it only accepts CLI args.

Comment: You could build a trivial Java program to use instead of anotherapplication.jar and see if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setsid should do what you want. I can't tell why your application doesn't start, but the application will not print anything to the /tmp/output.log, simply because you don't redirect output of the setsid line to the log file. I would redirect the stdout and stderr of that line to the output.log using:

```
(setsid java -jar ./anotherapplication.jar "$@" &) >>/tmp/output.log 2&>1
```

This will almost certainly show an error documenting why it fails to start. It's often a good idea to reset the standard input and output of daemon-like processes like this anyway.

Comment: I'm going to try this and report my findings